# Посоветуйте instagram api на python для публикации поста

Tags: python, api, cookie, instagram

Посоветуйте рабочий в 2020 году API для instagram на python.
Задача отправить картинку и описание в instagram (обычный пост). 
Перепробовал, много различных API. Пришел к выводу, что сейчас обязательно подвязывать cookie, иначе блокирует сам instargam ("challenge_required"). 
Пробую следующий код (естественно подставляя свой логин и пароль и полный путь к cookie)

```
from instapy_cli import client

username = 'USERNAME'
password = 'PASSWORD'
cookie_file = 'COOKIE_FOR_USER.json' # default: `USERNAME_ig.json`

cli=client(username, password, cookie_file=cookie_file,  write_cookie_file=True)
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Unexpected Exception: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

В чем может быть дело пока не понял. Будет полезен рабочий пример кода на Python.
И как правильно доставать cookie из Firefox? Я это делал при помощи расширения Cookie Quick Manager.

Comment: Можете привести полный трейсбек ошибки?

Comment: Это и есть полный трейсбек

Comment: В полном обычно указывается в каком модуле возникла ошибка и на какой строке. В вашем коде нет ничего похожего на список, значит ошибка возникает где-то в самой библиотеке.

Comment: Всё что выше этой ошибки, начиная с текста `Traceback (most recent call last):`. -- полный трейсбек.

Comment: Я понимаю. Но больше ничего не выдает. В этом то и проблема. Я уже и модули пересмотрел. Там нет list

Comment: А какая версия Python?

Comment: Версия Python 3.6